# Google Maps Custom Polygon with image as background and hover effect

Tags: html, google-maps, polygon

Is it possible to create a webapp using Google Maps API V3 that uses custom images for countries or regions, that change on mouseover and mouseclick?

I have looked at google.maps.GroundOverlay and ProjectedOverlay but haven't found a solution. An example would be also great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible..there are a couple ways to do it

One way is to use OverlayView - see demo here [Showing/Hiding overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow)

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays):

- Set the custom object's prototype to a new instance of google.maps.OverlayView(). This will effectively "subclass" the overlay class.
- Create a constructor for your custom overlay, and set any initialization parameters to custom properties within that constructor.
- Implement an onAdd() method within your prototype, and attach the overlay to the map. OverlayView.onAdd() will be called when the map is ready for the overlay to be attached..
- Implement a draw() method within your prototype, and handle the visual display of your object. OverlayView.draw() will be called when the object is first displayed as well.
- You should also implement an onRemove() method to clean up any elements you added within the overlay.

After that, you would then need to add an eventListener on the map for the click event for instance to activate this OverlayView, here's an example of how to add a click eventListener on the map https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments